# Angular 2 : SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, reactivex

I know this kind of questions are already asked and I also referred to all those answered questions but still I couldn't resolve the issue.
This error is occurring exactly when I deploy                             `import 'rxjs/add/operator/fromArray';` Except this `import` and `Observable.fromArray` the code works flawlessly.
I'm on **angular 2.0.0-beta.7**

**Error thrown on to the console**

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <(…)
Zone.run                                       @angular2-polyfills.js:1243
zoneBoundFn                                    @angular2-polyfills.js:1220
lib$es6$promise$$internal$$tryCatch            @angular2-polyfills.js:468
lib$es6$promise$$internal$$invokeCallback      @angular2-polyfills.js:480
lib$es6$promise$$internal$$publish             @angular2-polyfills.js:451
lib$es6$promise$$internal$$publishRejection    @angular2-polyfills.js:401
(anonymous function)                           @angular2-polyfills.js:123
Zone.run                                       @angular2-polyfills.js:1243
zoneBoundFn                                    @angular2-polyfills.js:1220
lib$es6$promise$asap$$flush                    @angular2-polyfills.js:262
```

**app.component.ts**

```
   import {Component} from "angular2/core";
   import {Observable} from "rxjs/Rx";
   import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
   import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
   import 'rxjs/add/operator/fromArray';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: ` 
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
          `
   })

export class AppComponent {
constructor(){
    var startDates = [];
    var startDate = new Date();

    for ( var day = -2; day <=2; day++){
        var date = new Date(
            startDate.getFullYear(),
            startDate.getMonth(),
            startDate.getDate() + day);
    }

    startDates.push(date);

    Observable.fromArray(startDates)
        .map(date => {
                     console.log('Getting deal for the date ' + date);
                     return [1, 2, 3];
                     })
        .subscribe(x => console.log(x));

   }
}
```

**index.html**

```
 <html>
   <head>
      <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/styles.css">
  <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
  <!-- IE required polyfills, in this exact order -->
<script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"> </script>
 <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
<script>
System.config({
    packages: {
        app: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
    }
});
System.import('app/boot')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
  </script>
</head>

<!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
     <my-app>
      Loading...
     </my-app>
   </body>
  </html>
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
  {
    "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
     "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
},
  "exclude": [
  "node_modules",
  "typings/main",
  "typings/main.d.ts"
   ]
 }
```

**package.json**

```
 {
   "name": "angular2-quickstart",
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "scripts": {
   "start": "concurrent \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
   "tsc": "tsc",
   "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "typings": "typings",
    "postinstall": "typings install"
   },
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.7",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
     "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
     "systemjs": "0.19.22",
     "zone.js": "0.5.15"
  },
     "devDependencies": {
     "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
     "lite-server": "^2.1.0",
      "typescript": "^1.7.5"
    }
   }
```

Comment: try using `.map` function in index.html i.e `.map:{rxjs: 'node_modules/rxjs'
}`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand you're code :)

Comment: i mean to say try adding `.map:{rxjs: 'node_modules/rxjs' }` code into your index.html  file where you define `System.config` .  have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/34440018/5043867

Comment: Still didn't work!

Comment: whats the error now ?

Comment: same error as before!

Comment: You don't need `import 'rxjs/add/operator/fromArray'` since you are importing `Observable` from `rxjs/Rx` not from `rxjs/observable`. Not to mention the correct import should've been: `import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromArray'`  in the first place.

Comment: I'm having the same error from the same Udemy course. Were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could use the "from" operator instead of the "fromArray" one:

```
Observable.from(startDates)
    .map(date => {
      (...)
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try importing from observable path for fromArray operator.

import 'rxjs/add/**observable**/fromArray';

Here's a working example:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromArray'

import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: ``
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor() {
        Observable.fromArray([1, 2, 3])
            .map(data => "Value = " + data)
            .subscribe(x => console.log(x));
    }
}
```